# Can you nest Excel data tables?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, nested

I have an Excel workbook that utilises a data table (A).

I now want to create another data table (B) that effectively sits on top of the other data table. That is, each "iteration" of B calls A.

This approach fails although I cannot find any documentation about data tables that indicates that this would not work.

Basically I'd like to know if anyone has tried this before and whether I am missing something?

Is there a workaround? Do you know of any documentation that spells out whether and why this is not supported?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

I  tried this at length some years ago in both xl03 and xl07 and my conclusion was that it can't be done -  each data table seems to be an independent one-off run, they don't talk if you try to link them

I couldn't find any documentation on this issues either on the process, or for anyone else looking at a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response Dave. Glad to know someone else in the world wanted this functionality -- makes me feel less lonely. :)

Comment: As a fellow Data Table taric you might find this useful, [this code](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=453) will remove then add back in data tables :)

Comment: Brett, sorry just saw your further comments from a few weeks ago. Where is the code you refer to that removes and adds back data tables. I found an approach to this but wasn't happy with it so developed my own method to delete and create them (using a lookup table approach). I'd be keen to see your method.

Comment: @daxmiller , can you access the code at [vbaexpress here] (http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=453) ? The code is from 2004 so needs a tidyup for xl07 and it isn't as pretty as I'd like it to be but it should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I want to share my experience using the data tables.
We have found a workaround for this problematic.
If you have two variables A & B that need to run into a datatable and get one or multiple result.

What we've done is :
Set any combinaison (binari combinaison) for A & B and put an id for each of this combinaison (A=0 & B=0 => id=1)
So you will then run one data table with a length of A*B.
The default here is the length to calculate those data (7min with 25 data table & 2 data table with a length of 8000 rows).

Hope it help !